# Metamask javascript send money in a specific crypto token

Tags: javascript, metamask

im trying to make a payment button for metamask but i dont know how to choose a specift crypto do send the value.

here is my code:

```js
const ethereumButton = document.querySelector('.enableEthereumButton');
    const sendEthButton = document.querySelector('.sendEthButton');

    let accounts = [];

    //Sending Ethereum to an address
    sendEthButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      ethereum
        .request({
          method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
          params: [
            {
              from: accounts[0],
              to: 'MYWALLETHERE',
              value: '0x38d7ea4c68000'
            },
          ],
        })
        .then((txHash) => console.log(txHash))
        .catch((error) => console.error);
    });

    ethereumButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      getAccount();
    });

    async function getAccount() {
      accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });   
      
    }
    getAccount();
```

```html
 <button class="enableEthereumButton btn">Enable Metamask</button>
        <button class="sendEthButton btn">Fazer pagamento</button>
```

how can i force a crypto like BNB here in Binance smart chain?

Comment: https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/wallet/wallet_api.html

Comment: i didint understand how can i input it on my code sorry :(